# When is the best time to ask a question?

Tags: discussion

I am assuming that the attention a question gets depends to some extent on when it is submitted. If this is the case, would it not be sensible to ask the question when it is most likely to be noticed? My guess is that this would be the weekend.

Comment: are you asking when peak activity is on the site?

Comment: Surely you wait a couple of days to ensure enough experts have seen the question and had an opportunity to answer it.  Or if you're in a blinding hurry to fix a crisis you ask immediately.  Time is irrelevant.

Comment: On Security Stack Exchange, the weekend is almost certainly the worst time to submit if you want the most attention. Monday to Thursday afternoon UK time (morning US time) seems to be best. This is based entirely on my own anecdotal experience watching posts come in.

Comment: What @RoryAlsop said... But truthfully, we do not have such a high rate of traffic at any time, that your post would get lost in the flood - as could sometimes happen on [SO] for example. As Chenmunka said, its not like you need an immediate, within-seconds answer - so just post whenever is good for you, and check back later.

Comment: The best time to ask a question is after you have though about it, done some research to find the answer yourself, and written the draft in an editor. Of course, it helps to do that before you forget what the question was, or other things get in the way and you don' thave time to do it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

There aren't so many quesitons being asked here that you risk going unnoticed unless you post on the optimal time. Just post whenever you want to. The timing is really a non issue.

If you are concerned about not getting good answers, I would suggest you read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That will be more useful than trying to get the timing right.

Comment: Also, I find it quite hard to generalize whether more overall activity actually has a good or a bad effect on getting high-quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

Questions which do not receive much attention (and which do not have upvoted answers) are occasionally bumped to the homepage. This does a lot to reduce any effect the timing of posting might have on the attention received.